# Importing tflearn is very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

Importing tflearn takes a large amount of time compared to other modules.

On a newly created virtual environment with only tflearn and minimal dependencies installed with `pip`:

- `import numpy as np` takes ~0.18s
- `import tensorflow as tf` takes ~0.90s
- `import tflearn` takes ~3.1s (and asks me to install h5py and scipy).

After installing h5py and scipy as suggested, time consumed by `import tflearn` goes up to ~3.5s.  How can I reduce importing time?

(All tests above are done by putting the statement in test.py and run `time python test.py` several times.  The reported time is the "real" time as reported by `time` builtin of bash.)

Comment: You can use `time` module in python for more accurate measuring.

import time

start = time.time()
import numpy as np
print(time.time() - start)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The short answer

Do your initial work in Jupyter or something else that has a long-lived interpreter session, so you don't need to wait around for imports that much.

## The long answer

You can use `python -v` to trace imports.  I installed `moreutils` from apt and `tensorflow` and `tflearn` from `pip` in a pristine `python:3.6-stretch` Docker container...

```
root@10e4bcd91377:/# python -v -c 'import tensorflow' 2>&1 | ts '%H:%M:%.S' | grep 'import ' | wc -l
954
root@10e4bcd91377:/# python -v -c 'import tflearn' 2>&1 | ts '%H:%M:%.S' | grep 'import ' | wc -l
1768
```

It's immediately clear that importing `tflearn` imports a whole lot of packages.
Which ones?

```
# python -v -c 'import tflearn' 2>&1 | grep 'import ' | cut -f1 -d# | sort | uniq > tflearn-imports.txt
# python -v -c 'import tensorflow' 2>&1 | grep 'import ' | cut -f1 -d# | sort | uniq > tensorflow-imports.txt
# diff --suppress-common-lines tensorflow-imports.txt tflearn-imports.txt
```

I'll spare the 831 lines of output, but it looks like `tflearn` imports all of `tensorflow.contrib`, which is taking quite a while, and it's not something importing `tensorflow` itself does. Armed with this info, we can look at the original `python -v -c 'import tflearn' 2>&1` output – it looks like `tflearn.variables` is the module importing `tensorflow.contrib`...

```
# <snip>
import 'tensorflow.contrib.summary.summary'
import 'tensorflow.contrib'
import 'tflearn.variables'
import 'tflearn.config'
# <snip>
```

Could it be [this `from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope` statement](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/8aa8436a641f019983a4d5ea2290ba98eed8a181/tflearn/variables.py#L7)? Let's find out...

```
# time python -v -c 'from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope' 2>&1 | grep 'import ' | wc -l
1727

real    0m4.010s
user    0m3.820s
sys 0m0.410s
root@10e4bcd91377:/#
```

Ayup, looks like it! Due to the way Python's importing works, importing a submodule has to evaluate the whole package, and since `tensorflow.contrib` doesn't use [Tensorflow's Python lazy loader (which does mention `contrib`)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4292085f549afc7d7e9ac5dc517b2bab45c79ad3/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py#L29), it takes a while.

(There used to be discussion about vendoring in the module here, but that's irrelevant, because:)

Unfortunately there are other places within `tflearn` that also import bits and pieces from `contrib`, so swatting out this dependency won't help much.

Comment: I actually raised an issue for this over at the tflearn project. https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/1069

Comment: Thanks for the `-v` trick, it's really useful for locating the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Some imported modules initialize when you start using them, some aren't. The `tflearn` initialise when you import it and since it has a lot of dependencies it's not surprisingly that it takes that much time.

The SO QA Below will give you idea of optimization that long time.

[improving speed of Python module import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373510/improving-speed-of-python-module-import)

Good luck