# How to speed up loading module in Python 3

Tags: python, import, module

Using python 3.6.7 - it takes 0.8 seconds to start a python code with 1 line of code:

`import dask.dataframe as dd`

How to speed up importing this module? Should I compile or run it with pypy (if yes - what is the process?)

Thanks.

Comment: You gave two ideas already. What were the results when you tested them?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what were your results when you ran it with pypy? I suggest using [PyOxidizer](https://github.com/indygreg/PyOxidizer) to produce the executable, just like this [post](https://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2018/12/28/faster-in-memory-python-module-importing/) suggests. Also, a pretty neat solution is to have your imports in a server program and the rest in a client, just like this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373510/improving-speed-of-python-module-import) mentions.

Finally, have you checked the official wiki on [Performance Tips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)?