# Python: slow imports of Surprise, formerly scikit-surprise, and Pandas

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

I made a recommendation system prototype using Surprise and Pandas Dataframe. I also made a command-line tool that takes in some parameters (like user id, type of recommendation, etc...), the main problem is that importing Pandas and Surprise takes way too much time and I need it to run the script in less than a second. The code is already optimized and I also added some caching features to it.
Is there a way to optimize import time or speed it up a bit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [improving speed of Python module import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373510/improving-speed-of-python-module-import)

Comment: I want to avoid a client-server approach :/