# Very long startup latency on Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I am deploying a python [project](https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg) on google cloud run using the following Dockerfile. When no container is started, the cold container startup take around 35 seconds.

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as build

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt update -y && \
    apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install -y curl software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.9

WORKDIR /rembg

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
RUN python3.9 -m pip install .

RUN mkdir -p /home/.u2net/

RUN mv u2netp.onnx /home/.u2net/u2netp.onnx
RUN mv u2net.onnx /home/.u2net/u2net.onnx
RUN mv u2net_human_seg.onnx /home/.u2net/u2net_human_seg.onnx
RUN mv u2net_cloth_seg.onnx /home/.u2net/u2net_cloth_seg.onnx

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["rembg"]
CMD ["s"]
```

With another nodeJs project I am using `FROM ubuntu:20.04` as build and the startup latency is 4 seconds. I tried to do the same python project but it didn't helped. Any idea about the problem?

Comment: Your post includes details on how you built the container. Your post does not include details on the application you are running in the container.

Comment: I thought this is a docker problem. I updated the question by adding the project I am deploying

Comment: post your requirements.txt to your question, but as I posted as answer, this is how Python works on slow start, it's nothing wrong with Cloud Run, neither your container, it's a python "import" thing to be slow

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at the requirements.txt file, 99% the problems will be from there, from some heavy Python packages.

In Python environment on Cloud Run the cold start is a problem because GIL is not effective. More about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66047311/slow-numpy-and-pandas-imports-on-google-cloud-run).

Marginally you can make it better with Python 3.11, and if you have slim packages use those package-name@slim, similar to ML packages when no GPU needed @cpu annotation will pull different package. We've been applyied this improvements and our cold start reduced from 19 sec to 16 sec. So as I see, it's just marginally. You need to make sure that minimum instances are 1, to have your API always up, and then you don't have a frequent cold starts, only occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Pentium10's answer, you can also use [CPU boost](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu#startup-boost) (currently in preview/beta) wherein it provides additional CPU during [container instance startup time](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#startup) and for **800** seconds after the instance has started. The actual boost will depend on your CPU limit settings (e.g., CPU limit: 0-1, boosted CPU: 2).

You may refer to the following documentation on preventing cold starts and optimizing performance:

- [Cloud Run optimizing performance](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#optimize_performance)
- [New startup CPU boost improves cold starts in Cloud Run, Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/announcing-startup-cpu-boost-for-cloud-run--cloud-functions)